# How to import ReactJS Material UI using a CDN through Webpack's externals?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, cdn

### The Problem:

I'm trying to create a website (web app) with [React](https://reactjs.org/) and [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/), it's working just fine using npm. But when I try to make them as `externals` and import them through a CDN instead, I get an error with Material UI (React works fine).

### My Code:

I linked CDNs in **index.html** like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.min.js"></script>
```

And in **app.min.js**, I imported them like this:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
```

### My Attempt:

In the **webpack.config.js**, I tried the following (again, only Material UI causes an error):

1. Using a string:

   ```
   externals: {
     'react': 'React',
     'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
     '@material-ui/core': 'Button'
   }
   ```

   gives:

   > Uncaught ReferenceError: Button is not defined
2. Using an object:

   ```
   externals: {
     'react': 'React',
     'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
     '@material-ui/core': {
       Button: '@material-ui/core'
     }
   }
   ```

   gives:

   > TypeError: Cannot read property 'Button' of undefined
3. Doing it manually, so Material UI isn't in externals:

   ```
   externals: {
     'react': 'React',
     'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
   }
   ```

   Then removing minified Material UI code from **app.min.js**, this leaves the code incomplete and it doesn't run.
4. Searched through GitHub issue and SO questions without any luck, some links:

   - [How should material-ui be externalized when bundling with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102609)
   - [Externals defined in webpack.config still getting error module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823313)
   - [React CDN: Webpack externals library not resolved in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632894)

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**:

in webpack.config.js:

```
externals: {
  'react': 'React',
  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
  'material-ui': 'window["material-ui"]'
},
```

then in app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'material-ui';
```

**Explanation:**

If you check the cdn version of material ui js, you will find it exports its content in to `material-ui` namespace.

[image]

if you config webpack like:

```
'material-ui': 'material-ui'
```

webpack will compile it to:

[image]

which leads to the code looking for `material` and `ui` in global environment which does not exist. So we have to specify `window["material-ui"]` explicitly

Comment: This solution does not work for more recent releases of Material UI, around `4.1.x` onwards.

Answer (score 7):

Might be a little late to the party but I will add an answer which worked for me.

**step 1:**

add the script tag from unpkg. The difference between this and cdnjs is that unkpg have an option for umd. May or may not be an issue in your particular situation. It is for me.
url:
https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.11.0/umd/material-ui.production.min.js

script tag:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.11.0/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
```

**step 1b:**

add the font and font icon external resources as described in the material-ui docs:

[material-ui getting started - installation guide](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)

roboto font:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
```

font icons:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

**step 2:**

destructure the elements you want to use from window.MaterialUI or use the square bracket notation (but unnecessary here since this package ditched the '-' char.

```
const { Button } = window['MaterialUI'];
```

**step 3:**

use the element as you 'normally' would

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary">
  Primary
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this issue after spending way too much time on this issue while trying to build an app using a micro-frontend architecture.

**TL;DR;**

The solution is to put the following in the `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // rest of the config clipped for brevity
  externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-router-dom': 'ReactRouterDOM',
    '@material-ui/core': 'MaterialUI'
  }
};
```

**Further details:**

I was building a macro-frontend composed of multiple micro-frontends. Each of the micro-frontends was developed in React, exported as a web-component, and would be independently deployed such that each micro-frontend would be available via a URL like:

- `http://foo.example.com/main.js`
- `http://bar.example.com/main.js`
- `http://baz.example.com/main.js`

These would be imported into the macro-app using a `<script>` tag.

The macro-app was hosted on a separate domain, e.g., `http://example.com`.

The issue I was facing was that Material UI (and possibly React as well) was being initialized multiple times in each of the micro-apps.

To avoid that, I had to externalize all these libraries using the webpack config block above.

I had to make 2 concessions.

1. I did not use `create-react-app` and `react-scripts` to scaffold the macro-app because that setup would hide the webpack config. In order to expose the webpack config, I could either eject the CRA project, or use some other modules, such as `react-app-rewired`, etc. That felt like too much work. The downside of this was that I could not use `BrowserRouter` and had to accept using `HashRouter` for client-side routing.
2. I could not use `SvgIcon`-based icons from `@material-ui/icons`, because I could not find a good way of externalizing Material UI Icons. Instead, I put in a link to Material UI Icons stylesheet, and opted to use `Icon` from `@material-ui/core/Icon` to render icons. using `SvgIcon`-based icons was causing Material UI to be initialized in the micro-apps too, which is what I was trying to avoid. One upside of the workaround is that `Icon` works with `Font Awesome` as well, so at least all icons would be written consistently in code.

Overall, I am happy with the end results.