# Can I add only Material-UI Lab to my project without installing Core?

Tags: reactjs, npm, slider, material-ui, yarnpkg

I want to use the Slider component from Material UI in my React app.
The Slider is part of 'Lab', a 'package that hosts the incubator components that are not yet ready to move to the core.'

```
npm install @material-ui/lab
npm install @material-ui/core
```

Do I still need to install Core Material UI to my project or can I only add the Lab?
I do not want to add more bulk to my already big project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@material-ui/lab have dependency on @material-ui/core, so you must need to added @material-ui/core.it's your choice how you added npm install or cdn

here some useful for you i guess:

@material-ui/core cdn reference: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645796/how-to-import-reactjs-material-ui-using-a-cdn-through-webpacks-externals)

@material-ui/lab cdn reference: [Here](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@material-ui/lab)

or you can try [ant.design](https://ant.design/components/carousel/)
they have some awesome tools for you.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

`@material-ui/lab` has `@material-ui/core` as a peer dependency. So yes you do need to add it. However if you're concerned about bundle size then rest assured that importing a lab component will not add the complete core to the bundle. It will only add what's necessary.